# Why use ReaderWriterLockSlim.EnterReadLock?

Tags: c#, multithreading

[Based on Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.enterreadlock?view=net-6.0#remarks) `EnterReadLock` is used on locking in read mode. It also says multiple threads can read but only one thread can write at a time.

Why we should use `EnterReadLock` while multiple threads can access the same data? What happens if we don't lock on reading, but lock on writing?

Answer (score 8):

Read lock prevents acquiring write lock (`EnterWriteLock` will block until there are no more read or write locks acquired by others), but allows acquiring other read locks. If you don't use `EnterReadLock` on reads - the effect is other thread can acquire write lock and write data at the same time other threads read it, essentially defeating the usage of `ReaderWriterLock` completely.